# Car 'Jump Starter Pack' says Up to 2lt engine. Is this a strict limit?

Tags: battery, jump-start

I really appreciate all help I am given here and hope you can help me with this next problem.

Basically I have a 2.2 CDTI Honda Civic from 2008.
I need a jump starter pack  (because nobody I knows has a car to help me, and the Honda has been sat unused for several weeks). I don't have spare money to buy a top-notch Jumper Pack but I have seen one in Halfords (https://www.halfords.com/motoring/battery-maintenance/jump-starters/halfords-6-in-1-jump-starter-power-pack-654898.html) which I can afford.

However it states 'up to 2lt engine' in the advert.

I really hope this will be ok for my 2.1lt. But I have wasted much money recently so I wanted to ask here first for re-assurance.

(Sorry for this noob question again! :D )

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't buy a (much cheaper) charger and charge the car battery before starting? Like you can't get mains to the vehicle or the battery to near a mains socket, or you don't dare disconnect the battery from the vehicle (you can usually still charge it then, but I wouldn't use a fast charger with it connected to the vehicle electronics)

Comment: If you already had that pack I'd say charge it, connect it to the car for a couple of hours, disconnect it and then try starting the car without it.  If that fails, recharge the starter pack and use it for jumping with a topped-up battery.  Also Halfords don't have a clue about giving worthwhile specifications - they don't even state the capacity of the battery included in it

Comment: I can't really get the battery out. I am a complete idiot when it comes to cars and end up breaking bits or losing small bits. During summer I did run extension cable outside to the car but its a long way from the house and a little dangerous. I think I will buy the jump pack and hope for the best. I'm sure it will be of use some time in future anyway. Thanks for your help Chris I think I was worrying too much.

Comment: Just as a comment because I do not "know" the specifics on your jump pack, but...I have a similar quality and price item, a Schumacher SJ1329. "600 Peak amp Jump Starter". Below your 650 Amp item. I've successfully jump started the 4.2L V-6 in my F-150, after it sat for 8 months due to COVID. I suspect that 2L limit is a very conservative CYA.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a strict limit but I'm sure their testing has indicated that it works best with engines smaller than 2L.  What may happen is that this will not have enough energy to start your engine especially if it's cold.

If it's a problem you can always use it as a charger to help bring your installed battery up and then take a recharge the jump box and then try jumping the car.  That will give you the energy you stored in the car's battery plus the energy in the jump box together which should be adequate to start your 2.2L engine.

I also suspect that it will work fine as 2.2L is only 10% more than 2L.  It's not an exact science and it will probably work.